# Jsx element in getOptionLabel prop in autocomplete api in material ui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

getOptionLabel returns a string, is there a way that can return jsx element, this will increase the customization.

Currently:
[This doesn't has the airportNames it only has the iata code and operation city](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I5XEG.png)

Desired:
[This contains the AirportNames and it has iata code and the operation city](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Tp4s.png)

PS: I have airport Names in my api, I only need a way to make this happen which I might suggest is my passing JSX elements to getOptionLabel prop inside autocomplete API, but it only takes string

````
const defaultProps = {
        options: list,
        getOptionLabel: (option) => `${option.iata} (${option.cityServed})`,
      };

    return(
        <div className={classes.SourceDestination}>
            <div className={classes.Source}>

            <Autocomplete
                {...defaultProps}
                className="AirportSelectTextAuto"
                openOnFocus
                id="Source"
                value={Source}
                onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                setSource(newValue);
                textInput.current.focus();
                getSource(newValue)
                }}
                renderInput={(params) => <TextField className="AirportSelectText" {...params} label="Source" margin="normal" />}
            />
         </div>
)```
````

Comment: You can use the `renderOption` prop for this purpose. See this example in the documentation: https://material-ui.com/components/autocomplete/#githubs-picker.

Comment: @RyanCogswell hi thanks for the answer do you mind if you could help me with this code, I am little bit new.. -Thanks

Comment: I recommend that you try to work through it and if you get stuck, create a more specific question for that problem including a [code sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/new) (as well as including the relevant code in your question) that shows what you are trying to do.